# Linux GUI: gnuplot, bash script, octave

Tags: linux, user-interface, gnuplot, octave

Is there any way to write a GUI under Ubuntu that one can work with  gnuplot, octave and bash scripts together?

Comment: Just use any terminal emulator: open in one tab octave and in other - `cd` to octave's working directory.

Comment: I want to build a user interface. When I push a button for example, bash scripts will do its job.

Comment: That's possible only for a very limited number of actions. GUI is a useful thing only in browser or image/music/video editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to make the GUI and call the scripts, be  it octave, bash or gnuplot. You could probably make the plots in the GUI and forget octave. At the end I learned a little bit of ruby on rails to offer my fortran code on the cloud.

For example, You could use qt and call the octave function usino a system call. Or go web based and make an ajax call. There are just too many options, depending on which language/framework/libraries you use.

To make a script call from octave, see http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Controlling-Subprocesses.html . There are many ways to do it. Depending on what you want, a mere

```
    system("./my_script")
```

could do the job. If you need to get the response, there is info on that link. Otherwise, the script could put the output in a file that you could read later from octave.

If you want to get input in octave, so that you make something close to a very light weighted user interface, you could make a loop and inside ask for input. For example

```
    while x>0
        x = input("Enter an integer (0 for quiting), 5 for script")
        if (x==5)
            system("./my_script")
        endif
    endwhile
```

Comment: Actually calling bash scripts from octave would work enough for me, however I don't know how to do it. I don't know ajax. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I added how to make a call to a script from octave on my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. That solves more than half of the problem.

Comment: You should probably take a look at scilab. It's similiar to octave, graphics and all, plus you can make GUI from within. I once learned, and it wasn't that difficult.

Comment: I have many scripts in octave, so I am afraid that they have to be modified when working with scilab. Or no?

Comment: Not too much. I added how to get user input. At least that should get you started. I once made something similar using bash, before learning c++. The script called many c functions. If this satisfies your question, don't forget to mark the answer.

Comment: @newzad you can try the experimental octave GUI. You'll have to build the testing version (3.7.2) from source thought. See [their wiki](http://wiki.octave.org/Debian) for instructions.